# Basic auth :Unable to login to a URL. The issue is that the username requires domain name and hence we need "\"

Tags: basic-authentication

Using Chrome Browser-
For Example,
http://example.com

Username is- abc\User123
Password is- password123

When I try to navigate to http://abc\User123:password123@example.com, it does not work as chrome tries to go to http://abc/User123:password123@example.com.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%5C` instead of `\` in user name. So `abc\User123` should be `abc%5CUser123`.